# Missing out of the box workflow template

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am trying to build simple Out of the box workflow and I have noticed that some workflow templates are missing:
[image]

I have try to activate workflow feature under Site Collection Feature but I am still unable to see the other workflow template including:

- Collect Feedback - SharePoint 2010
- Collect Signatures - SharePoint 2010
- Approval- SharePoint 2010

Any other suggestions?. Thank you

Comment: Activate the Workflow feature which is under Site Collection Features section.

Comment: WHICH feature do you activate for the Approval workflow? I've got **Disposition Approval Workflow**, **Three-state workflow**, and **Workflows** active in site features but the only OOTB workflows I can add to a list are Disposition Approval and Three-state. There are these other features not active that have the word "approval" in them. Should I activate one of them? **Project Server Approval Content Type** or **Publishing Approval Workflow**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolve this issue by doing following:

1. Stop timer job and clear configuration cache
2. If step one is not working, reboot the machine.
3. Then deactivate and re-activate Workflow feature under site collection administration ->  site collection features